# Run a script for a determied amount of time

Tags: macos, timer, applescript

I'd like to run an applescript for a determined amount of time.
When the counter reaches 0 the script should stop working.

I've found online a timer code like this one:

```
set input to text returned of (display dialog "Enter length of timer" default answer "")
delay input
beep
```

But instead of waiting for that amount of time I'd like to perform all the cycles and actions of my script. Is there any easy way to achieve that?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Doing something like that would require something on the lines of multithreading, which applescript doesn't have.  Try add a date variable at the start, and then keep comparing it until you meet the time requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set start to current date
repeat
    say "a"
    if (current date) - start ≥ 3 then exit repeat
    delay 1
end repeat
```